# Unable to join race on local server

Tags: code-rally

I installed the code rally server following th guide on IBM.

It runs, I can access the server information page and see the leaderboard.
But when I try to enter with Eclipse I get a

"Unable to enter Keepertje on Localhost"

I also try to connect with the nodeclient found on Github, but there I also cannot authenticate.  Am I missing something?

Kind regards,.
Cindy

My Server.xml:

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>


<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

<webApplication id="CodeRallyWeb" location="CodeRallyWeb.war" name="CodeRallyWeb"/>
```

Error:

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [9-2-17 15:17:13:214 CET]
Exception = javax.servlet.ServletException
Source = com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters
probeid = 1064
Stack Dump = javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no value matching -1 id
    at com.ibm.coderally.web.service.DatabaseServletUbi.doPost(DatabaseServletUbi.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1157)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4956)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:525)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1014)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no value matching -1 id
    at com.ibm.coderally.api.ai.CheckpointAI.getById(CheckpointAI.java:109)
    at com.ibm.coderally.web.service.SubmitVehicle.buildIntermediateRaceCar(SubmitVehicle.java:421)
    at com.ibm.coderally.web.service.SubmitVehicle.doPost(SubmitVehicle.java:307)
    at com.ibm.coderally.web.service.DatabaseServletUbi.doPost(DatabaseServletUbi.java:61)
    ... 25 more

Dump of callerThis
null
```

[Make Vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqGym.png)
[All Vehicles in the corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVNG1.jpg)

Server.json

```
{"servers":[{"alias":"IBM Cloud","host":"http://www.coderallycloud.com","username":"someone","oauthType":null,"logoutURL":null,"port":80,"userId":77},{"alias":"NA Contest Server","host":"http://challenge-na.coderallycloud.com","username":"","oauthType":null,"logoutURL":null,"port":80,"userId":-1},{"alias":"EU Contest Server","host":"http://challenge-eu.coderallycloud.com","username":"","oauthType":null,"logoutURL":null,"port":80,"userId":-1},{"alias":"Brazil Contest Server","host":"http://challenge-br.coderallycloud.com","username":"","oauthType":null,"logoutURL":null,"port":80,"userId":-1},{"alias":"India Contest Server","host":"http://challenge-in.coderallycloud.com","username":"","oauthType":null,"logoutURL":null,"port":80,"userId":-1},{"alias":"China Contest Server","host":"http://challenge-cn.coderallycloud.com","username":"","oauthType":null,"logoutURL":null,"port":80,"userId":-1},{"alias":"MyOwnServer","host":"http://localhost","username":"Keepertje","oauthType":null,"logoutURL":null,"port":9080,"userId":1}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so you have not yet logged into the server according to the error message. To do so please click on the servers browser in Eclipse (the grey square icon next to the green + for creating new AIs). Once you have done that select your local server and login using the login button to the right - if the username does not exist it will create it and log you in. Once logged in you can request a new race and it should work (the user ID of -1 error message is displayed if you're not logged in - I'll have a look at getting that text changed for this circumstance to make it clearer).

Comment: I have logged in (added an Image). If I log in again with the same username it says the user is present at the server and if it is actually me again.

Comment: Just to confirm - when asking to enter a race did you choose the top option in the right-click menu, or the second option where you then selected the server? The top option doesn't always pick up username changes, but the second one does.

If you used the second option, can you go into <user directory>/user/.coderally (you may need to enable seeing hidden folders in your OS). Inside that folder is a servers.json file - can you paste the contents of that file please?

Comment: I click the manage server button and login. Then I Click the plus to make a new vehicle on my own local server. Then I do a right click on the vehicle in my list and pick: start a race on <myOwnServer> . Screenshots have been added, as well as the server.json

Comment: I can race when I choose Agent as Implementation instead of Intermediate. I can also log in using the nodeweb from github (I had to remove the http before localhost). The only problem I now have is that watching the play doesn't work. It places the cars in the top left corner of the screen underneath the traffic light.

Comment: The agent working instead of intermediate sounds like either the first server in your servers list is offline (if it is delete it from the servers list), or the Eclipse client is not saving the settings properly locally (this would be clear if you edit an intermediate car if the dropdowns are empty). The playback bug is JVM related - the simulation works correctly, and the times you get will be correct, but the rendering side of the server has a problem that puts all entities as close to 0,0 as it can. If you can install a different JVM and run the Liberty server on that it may fix it.

Comment: Jup, they are empty when I edit it. Will try with a different JVM. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Downloaded latest WLP, CodeRallyWeb and Eclipse plugins. Trying to race Intermediate Car local or IBM Cloud result in 'Unable to Enter' Server shows me as logged in.
Tried trace `*=info:com.ibm.coderally.*=all` but no extra info apart from 

    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no value matching -1 id
 at com.ibm.coderally.api.ai.CheckpointAI.getById(CheckpointAI.java:109)
 at com.ibm.coderally.web.service.SubmitVehicle.buildIntermediateRaceCar(SubmitVehicle.java:421)`

Comment: Hi Corneil - can you confirm that you have logged in to the local server? The ID of -1 indicates that you're not logged in.